# Error Compile Firebase library

Tags: android, firebase

I am implementing Firebase Notifications in my project, but getting a compilation error

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In sdk manager Play sevice an google repository is install and update.

The error log:

```
Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0
<a href="openFile:D:/dev/workspace/android/Music/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

What's wrong? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please include the error log.

Comment: my qustion is edited

Comment: Update your Google Play Services and Google Repository to latest version

Comment: What do you mean with "In sdk manager Play sevice an google repository is install and update"?

Comment: @Paul "Installed and updated" probably

Comment: yes instaled and updated

Comment: Is your problem solved by updating the Services?